# Partially expanding macro argument

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a library of tikz pictures, eg.

```
\newcommand*{\mypic}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
 %...
\end{tikzpicture}
 }
```

which I would like to print together with their names (including arguments).
However,

```
\renewcommand{\show}[1]{\verb|#1|\quad #1}
\show{\mypic{a}}
```

produces

> Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and might cause unrecoverable errors.

I guess \show is trying to expand its argument inside \verb. I experimented with \expandafter but it didn't help. When I replaced \verb| | with \texttt{}, \show didn't print the macro name at all.

Comment: `\verb` cannot appear inside another macro.

Comment: Try instead `\renewcommand{\show}[1]{\detokenize{#1}\quad #1}`

Comment: Also `\show` only takes a single token.  If you want to print multiple, try `\message{...}` or `\errmessage{...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's better to not redefine primitive, for example `\show`. Just choose another command name. Then, `\Verb` from `fvextra` package is more robust than `\verb`, when used inside another macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\mypic}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, circle] {text}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\showTikzPic}[1]{\Verb|#1|\quad #1}

\begin{document}
\showTikzPic{\mypic{}}
\end{document}
```

[image]